# I am running into a TypeError while using Path

Tags: python, pathlib

I am writing a program that sorts files in a folder and each time I run the program it sort both files in the target folder and files inside folders in the target folder.

I want the program to loop through a folder that contains folders and files and skip folders and work on files instead.

For Clarity: Folder A (Root folder) contains:

1. files
2. folders(B)

I keep running into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HighB33Kay\Documents\Projects\Personal\python\fileorganizer\osa.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\HighB33Kay\Documents\Projects\Personal\python\fileorganizer\osa.py", line 54, in main
    return sortDirectory(sys.argv[1], flag)
  File "C:\Users\HighB33Kay\Documents\Projects\Personal\python\fileorganizer\osa.py", line 21, in sortDirectory
    Path("out" / ext).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

This is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import sys


def sortDirectory(directory, func=shutil.copy):
    # declare the directory
    root = Path(directory)
    # if it is not the root directory return false
    if not root.is_dir():
        return 1
    # for each entry in root
    for entry in root.iterdir():
        # if not file exit the program
        if not entry.is_file():
            continue
        name = entry.stem
        ext = entry.suffix[1:]
        print(ext)
        # make output folder out and ext
        Path("out" / ext).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        
        if Path("out" / ext / entry.name).exists():
            count = 1
            for newFile in Path("out" / ext / entry.name):
                if name == "_".join(newfile.split('.')[0].split('_')[:-1]):
                    count += 1
            outfile = name+'_'+str(count)+'.'+ext
        else:
            output = entry
        print('File:', Path(root / ext / entry.name), '->', Path("out" / ext / entry.name))
        func(Path(root / ext / entry.name),Path("out" / ext / entry.name))
    return 0

def main():
    
    functionDict = {
        'm': shutil.move,
        'c': shutil.copy,
    }
    flag = shutil.copy
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        if sys.argv[2].lower()[0] in functionDict:
            flag = functionDict[sys.argv[2].lower()[0]]
        else:
            print("Unsupported 3rd argument. Use 'm'ove or 'c'opy")
            return 1

    elif len(sys.argv) == 1 or len(sys.argv) > 3:
        print(
            "Wrong amount of arguments. Only 2 arguments supported: [path function]")
        return 1

    return sortDirectory(sys.argv[1], flag)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I Appreciate Any Help Offered. Thank You.

Comment: Tips : are you trying to do a division? or a contatenation?
```root / ext / entry.name```

Answer (score 2):

[`/` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators) is implemented for Path objects. But you are applying this with `str` object. So you should change the code to

```
(Path("out") / ext).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```